# ruby on rails - Saving payment transaction with different currencies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, database-design, internationalization, currency

I am designing the DB for a site which will sell some services. The services may be in any currency depending on the country where they are sold.

I want to save the history of purchases of users, so that they can see them and also from which I can get reports on the income.

How should I save the transaction to generate those reports? Should I convert and save all the payment amounts to a single currency based in the daily value? Or should I get this information from the 3rd party payment processor?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should store in the original entered format, and then fill in the conversion rate from the payment processor.  Daily rates are great, but actual processors don't necessarily have the same rates all day, meaning you have to reconcile afterwards anyway.

Also if data is currently floated (for example, bank accounts in multiple currencies, or refunds payable in multiple currencies) in any other currency this keeps things consistent.